# How to generate more than one PDF and send through email attachment using PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf

How to generate more than one pdf and send with email attachment?

i am use fpdf php library to generate pdf and want to send multiple pdf attachment with email. so i have tried like,

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

// Generate first One.
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output('.assets/temp/download1.pdf','f');
$file1='.assets/temp/download1.pdf';

 // Generate Second PDF.
 $pdf = new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
 $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
 $pdf->Output('.assets/temp/download2.pdf','f');
 $file2='.assets/temp/download2.pdf';

 // use phpmailer to send email.
 // load attachments and messages.
 // send
 // unset files.
?>
```

this will create a error Message: FPDF error: The document is closed. because i cannot load two time without close document. so please ask me solution for send multiple pdfs through attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 'S' parameter istead of 'F'

```
$pdf1 = new FPDF();
$pdf1->AddPage();
$pdf1->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf1->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World1!');
$file1 = ".assets/temp/download1.pdf";
$pdf1content = $pdf1->Output('S');
file_put_contents($file1, $pdf1content);

$pdf2 = new FPDF();
$pdf2->AddPage();
$pdf2->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf2->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World2!');
/**/
$file2 = ".assets/temp/download2.pdf";
$pdf2content = $pdf2->Output('S');
file_put_contents($file2, $pdf2content);

// use phpmailer to send email.
// load attachments and messages.
// send unset files.
```

see http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

Comment: Thankyou very much @Andrea Manzi

Comment: you're welcome @vijay! Which version of FPDF do you use?

Comment: As of FPDF 1.81 the `$dest` parameter is the first argument of `Output()`. So no need for an empty string in the first argument. But I guess that's why you ask for the version number?

Comment: Exactly @JanSlabon, anyway `function Output( $dest = '', $name = '', $isUTF8 = false ) {` of 1.81 check parameters for backward compatibility `if( strlen( $name ) == 1 && strlen( $dest ) != 1 ) {
   // Fix parameter order
   $tmp = $dest;
   $dest = $name;
   $name = $tmp;
  }`